# WebClient.DownloadFile File Corrupt

Tags: c#, file, download, webclient

I'm trying to download files directly from a list of urls.

I was able to download most files successfully except for the *.docx*. I was able to download the *.docx* file, but when I try to open it, the error message shows that `"The file is corrupt and cannot be opened"`, when I try to repair it with Microsoft Word, I got another error message saying `"Microsoft Office cannot open this file because some parts are missing or invalid"`. I don't have any issue when download *pdf* files.

My code is very simple and it looks like this:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://somehost/somefile.docx", "C:\\somefolder\\somefile.docx");
webClient.Dispose(); //I added this line just to see if it will fix the problem but no it didn't
```

I went to the urls in the browser and make sure that the files does exist and are not corrupted. The urls are just fine and I was able to download files directly from the urls in a browser and the file opens.

**Additional Information:**

I did find one thing that's different for pdf url and docx url, but I really don't think it has anything to do with my problem. When I go to the pdf url in a browser, the *pdf* was displayed in the browser. However, when I go to the docx url, the page doesn't show anything, but the download for the file automatically starts. I don't think this will make a difference but just FYI.

**EDIT 10:38AM**

I just tried the Async method. I was able to download the docx file and open it, but it appear as a blank word document, which is still not correct. The same docx file I download from the browser does have content.

```
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://somehost/somefile.docx"),"C:\\somefolder\\somefile.docx");
```

Comment: Is the file public? Do you need special credentials to access it? Cookies etc?

Comment: @Arran the files are all public, it's a free online archive site

Comment: Not directly related, but instead of calling `Dispose` manually, look into the `using` keyword. It's better practice!

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I didn't have that line originally, I added it to see if will somehow download the file successfully but it didn't (just like what I was expecting). I also just tried and using keyword but the method doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you provide us the actual address of the file your are downloading?  I tried a .docx file on a test site, and it worked fine.

Comment: Does the problem lies with every .docs file or is it the specific one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for trying to help, I really appreciate it.

I realize that the problem was actually me not concatenating the url correctly. Right, a stupid mistake I made...

WebClient didn't throw error for incorrect format (for whatever reason), and my log file was not logging the actual url that I was trying to connect to, so I didn't realize it was doing the wrong thing.

Anyway, thank you all for the help and the comments that help me figure out what the problem was.

Comment: Now accept your answer as an answer so other users will not read the question any more.

Answer (score 0):

DownloadFileAsync downloads file in background, and your application probably terminates before download is completed.

You should wait for DownloadFileCompleted event, or use a DownloadFile method that will wait until file will be downloaded.